# expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 20 but received input with shape (None, 29)

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, evaluate, mlp, sgd

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_66 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 20 but received input with shape (None, 29)
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD

```
# Generate dummy data
import numpy as np
x_train = np.random.random((1000, 29))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 1)), num_classes=10)
x_test = np.random.random((100, 20))
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 1)), num_classes=10)

model = Sequential()
# Dense(64) is a fully-connected layer with 64 hidden units.
# in the first layer, you must specify the expected input data shape:
# here, 20-dimensional vectors.
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=20))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=20,
          batch_size=128)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

please, explained for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

learning:

- Keras models are built on Numpy arrays of input data and labels. To train a model, we usually fituse functions.
- Multi-layer artificial neural networks (MLP) for multi-class softmax classification:
  https://keras.io/ko/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/

#x_train, và x_test có dạng 2 chiều nên số cột của x_train là số chiều vào cho mạng ở trên.

Comment: Please write all of your posts content in English.